# Getting empty string when using git shortlog -sen in phpseclib

Tags: php, git, phpseclib

I'm using the [php lib phpseclib](https://phpseclib.com/) to ssh into the server and get some data output from commands. When I use the command `$sftp->exec('git shortlog -sen')` it returns an empty string.

Using `git shortlog -sen` from the command line works fine and returns data.

Using other git commands also works, I get a string as a result, ex.: `$sftp->exec('git log -1 --pretty=%cn')`.

Tried quiet mode, callbacks, etc.. What am I missing here?